# How do you remove everything that is not visible in an Excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have very little data. I have copy and pasted the values only within the same Excel Workbook but still the size is 5MB! I tried selecting the entire sheets and deleting everything ( that I can not see! ) but the file size is still 5MB!

I saved the files as XML (2003 ) and see that there are a lot of empty style values are being repeated!

Is there a quick way to tell excel to remove everything that is not visible ( or not selected )?

The only thing that worked was to create a new Excel Workbook and copy paste the selected region as Values only.  Is it alarming that things can be embedded in a file and passed from a person to person without anyone realizing there is something more in the file, or maybe I was just being paranoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paranoid :)

1. There are plenty of free utilities that will quickly delete rows/columns beyond the true last used cell, the excess formatting is often the culprit (depending on how the formatting has been applied)

http://www.asap-utilities.com

use the 'Sheets'  25 Remove unused empty columns/rows

Other

1. You can also use ASAP to delete unused styles
2. Use JKP's Name Manger to delete broken range names, http://www.jkp-ads.com/officemarketplacenm-en.asp
3. Bill Manville's findlink to find links (links can add size so if un-neccesary delete them , http://www.manville.org.uk/software/findlink.htm)
4. File size sometimes is due to corruption, if so "rebirth" the file by right click all sheets, "Move or Copy", tick 'create a copy' and move to a new book